# Constructor 0 arguments error

Tags: c#, constructor, compiler-errors, arguments

I am making a sports calender which has venues, events and athletes.

basically when I try to run the program, I get the error that "Sport2012.Venue does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments.

```
//Method to add a new Venue to program
    public void addVenue(Venue v)
    {
        m_Venue.Add(new Venue());
    }
```

The code above errors at the m_Venue.Add(new Venue());

```
    public String m_venueName;
    public String m_venueAddress;
    private List<Event> m_Events;

    public Venue(String venueName, String venueAddress)
    {
        m_venueName = venueName;
        m_venueAddress = venueAddress;
        m_Events = new List<Event>();
    }
```

The code above shows the constructor for Sport2012.Venue.

Basically do i create a new constructor or alter the first extract

Thanks in advance

Daniel

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted.......

Comment: I dont want to be trolling here, but you probably spent more time  typing this post, than searching for the source of the error ... Edit : J_mcnally downvote because the question is pointless

Comment: The error is caused by using a constructor that does not exist. When you define any constructor in a class, the default one disappears. Venue has only one constructor, and it takes two arguments. As the answers mention, the code is probably semantically wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

From your code, it looks like you're trying to add `v` to `m_Venue` so you should just say

```
public void addVenue(Venue v) {
    m_Venue.Add(v);
}
```

You want to add the instance of `Venue` that was passed in as a parameter `v`, not a new instance which is what `new Venue()` would be creating if a parameterless constructor existed.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose your addVenue method is not correct

```
public void addVenue(Venue v)
{
    // add the provided instance, not a NEW one
    m_Venue.Add(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# all non-static classes have an implicit default, parameter-less (no args) constructor, unless you explicitly create a constructor.  The act of defining any constructor means there is no longer an implicit constructor.  In this case, your class has a constructor that takes two arguments, therefore, you have no implicit constructor.  Your compiler catches it.  You need to either a) add a parameter-less constructor or b) change your instantiation (new Venue..) to use the existing constructor.

Just be aware of why your constructor takes those arguments in the first place.  Can your Venue object 'work' without a name or address?  And, is there another way to supply a name or address (e.g., using public property setters).  If so, you can think of those as optional.  In that case, your existing constructor is for convenience and you can safely add a parameterless constructor.  If you absolutely need Venue name/address and there is no way to set them without breaking encapsulation, then you should change the instantiation logic to supply the arguments.

Good rule of thumb is that the creator of the object supplies the object with its essential components/services/dependencies via the constructor.  Optional components/services/dependencies can be supplied after construction.

Answer (score 0):

m_Venue.Add(new Venue("lords", "london"));

if the add venue method already takes in a venue, then just do m_Venue.Add(v)

Answer (score 0):

```
m_Venue.Add(v); would get rid of that error
```

All classes in C# have a default constructor one with 0 arguments until you define a constructor.
Once you have explicitly defined a constructor you also need to add one with 0 arguments (if that is what you need)

Answer (score 0):

You have two minor conceptual errors here.

The first problem is you are creating a new Venue with no arguments -> `.Add(new Venue())`. The constructor of `Venue` takes two strings. This is the source of your compile error. `.Add(new Venue("foo", "bar"));` would compile, for example.

The second problem is that you are passing a `Venue` to the `addVenue` method but not adding it to the list. You probably meant `m_Venue.Add(v);` and this is probably what you should do.